# Why am getting Internal Server Error?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, internal-server-error

I am working on a membership signup/join form. The form data is submitted to another page called join.php on pressing submit button I am getting Internal Server Error message. Can anybody help me find the reason/mistake in my coding?  Though the data is successfully entered into database.

```
    <?php
    // file name : join.php

    $con = mysqli_connect("$DBHOST", "$DBUSER", "$DBPASS","$DBNAME");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $name   =   $_POST['name'];
    $phone  =   $_POST['phone'];
    $email  =   $_POST['email'];
    $city   =   $_POST['city'];
    $state  =   $_POST['state'];
    $ip =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name); 
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$phone);
    $city  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$city);
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$state);

    $check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `members` WHERE phone=".$phone." 
    OR  email=".$email." Limit 1";
    if (mysqli_query($con,$check)>=1){
    echo ("The phone number <strong>".$phone."</strong> or email <strong>
     ".$email."  </strong> address is already registered with us.");
    }else{
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `members` 
        (`name`,`email`, `phone`, `city`, `state`,`ip`, `regdate`)       
    VALUES('".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$city."',
           '".$state."','".$ip."', NOW('') )") 
    or die("MYSQL ERROR :".mysqli_error($con));

    /* PREPARE MESSAGE FOR EMAIL TO NEW MEMBER */
    header("Refresh=07;URL=./index.php");


    $headers4  = "<join@mydomain.com>"; 
    $headers  = "Reply-to: $headers4\n";
    $headers .= "From: $headers4\n";
    $headers .= "Errors-to: $headers4\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";

    $message  = "<br>Dear ".$name." <br><br>";
    $message .= "Thanks for joining.<br> Your details are";
    $message .= "<br>Name - ".$name." <br>Mobile No. - ".$phone."<br>";
    $message .= "Email - ".$email."<br>City, State - ".$city.",".$state."<br>";
    $message .= "<br>Regards,<br>Name";

    mail("".$email."", "Thanks for Joining", "".$message."", "".$headers."");


    echo "<p>Congratulations!<br>IP-".$ip."<br>Your data has been added 
    into our membership database.<br><strong>Thank you for joining.</strong>";

   }

   mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

Comment: 1 = `$con = mysqli_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASS,$DBNAME);`
also where do you gets does values from?

Comment: What does your server's error log say?

Comment: set ini_set("display_errors",1); in your file and check it.

Comment: [enable displaying errors in PHP](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/)

Comment: Since it's an internal server error, I'm guessing it's `header("Refresh=07;URL=./index.php");` that's causing you problems.

Answer (score 0):

So many mistakes in it.. Improve your code style to give its quality a boost.

Start by fixing the quotes, very missleading:

```
mail("".$email."", "Thanks for Joining", "".$message."", "".$headers."");
```

Should be

```
mail($email, 'Thanks for Joining', $message, $headers);

$check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `members` WHERE phone=".$phone." 
OR  email=".$email." Limit 1";
```

Has missing quotes too, I don't thinkg email and phone are numbers.

```
$check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `members` WHERE phone='".$phone."' 
OR  email='".$email."' Limit 1";
```

There is no header called Refresh, this is kinda Javascript style, but you need HTTP:

```
header("Refresh=07;URL=./index.php");
```

Fixed:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Finally enable error reporting to see what's really wrong.

Comment: ok I implemented the corrections suggested by experts here and now am getting this error : Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in /home/public_html/join.php on line 35 .. if(mysqli_query($con,$check)>=1){
The phone number 1234567890 or email tester@mydomain.com address is already registered with us. The data is not being added into mysql db table.

Comment: Oh! there was a wrong suggestion by @DanFromGermany to add quotes in line where ='".$phone."', but all other suggestion were helpful. I removed extra quote and now it works fine. Thanks everyone.